# Is there a way to have the Angular $http interceptors work with $.ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new in the Angular world, so be nice with me :)

I use the Trello client.js in my Angular application to get data from Trello. For handling the authentication scenarios I'd like to use `$http` interceptors for catching any 401 responses and invoke the Trello authorization procedure accordingly. The code is a normal $http response interceptor, something like...

```
function trelloSecurityInterceptor($injector, $q, securityRetryQueue){
  return {
    responseError: function(originalResponse){
      console.log('interceptor: ' + originalResponse.status);

      $q.reject(originalResponse);
    }
  };
}
```

I use the Trello client like

```
function loadAllBoards(){
  return authorize()
    .then(function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      Trello.get(
        'members/me/boards',
        function(result){
          $log.debug('retrieved boards');
          deferred.resolve(result);
        });

      return deferred.promise;
    });
}
```

The problem is that the interceptor isn't being invoked. This is due to the fact that Trello internally uses jQuery (`$.ajax`).

Is there a way/shortcut to bind jQuery to Angular in a way to have `$http` interceptors fire properly or do I have to do it myself (using `ajaxError` on jQuery or similar)??

Thx

Comment: Its probably better to mock the Trello interface. I'd put Trello in its own angular service that you could easily mock in a test.

Comment: Hmm...don't get how that should solve my probl. But btw, the loadAllBoards() is alread a function inside my ng service.